# What's the difference between DialogFragment and AppCompatDialogFragment in Android?

Tags: android, modal-dialog, material-design, material-components-android

I mean to say `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment` and `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`: the documentation says that the first one is a subclass of the second one and that the first one uses an `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog` in order to apply the AppCompat themes.
But which have I to use with Material Components for Android (MDC-Android)?

Comment: Use the DialogFragment. Check also : https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-dialogs-75c6d726f83a

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti But with this dialog (DialogFragment) I always end up with white background in night mode. I even posted an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165822034 when I was using AppCompat themes. And the answer on that issue suggested to use AppCompatDialogFragment. After I switched to Material Components, I still couldn't use DialogFragment for the same reason - in night mode dialog had white background